# How to read txt file in python line by line and set each line to a variable

Tags: python

I have dictionary code which is programmed in python and a word list, the python code which decrypts a specific encrypted text is here:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os

BLOCK_SIZE = 32

PADDING = '{'

# Encrypted text to decrypt
encrypted = "t0ed+TDTf4e1V3Vz94nAN+nj1uDgMPZnfd7BDyBoy/GeGk6LiImMBPPHvN8DcLgIhWo4ByqxpZby99nQpU8KuA=="

DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

f = open('words.txt')

for line in f.readlines():
    secret = line.rstrip('\n')
f.close()

if (secret[-1:] == "\n"):
    print "Error, new line character at the end of the string. This will not match!"
elif (len(secret) >= 32):
    print "Error, string too long. Must be less than 32 characters."
else:
    # create a cipher object using the secret
    cipher = AES.new(secret + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(secret) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING)

    # decode the encoded string
    decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encrypted)

    if (decoded.startswith('FLAG:')):
        print "\n"
        print "Success: "+secret+"\n"
        print decoded+"\n"
    else:
        print 'Wrong password'
```

I want the code to loop through all lines in the words.txt and try them to check if they are the right value for the decryption process, this code stops when it reads the first line and it output `wrong password`

Comment: `line.strip()` (will remove all whitespace characters at the start and end of the line) or `line.rstrip('\n')` (will remove all `\n` at end of the line)

Comment: The same error occurs again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `rstrip()` it removes all the whitespaces along with the new line(`\n`). So use `rstrip('\n')` to remove the newlines only. As you want to loop it put the logic inside a `for` loop.

```
f = open('words.txt')

for line in f.readlines():
    secret = line.rstrip('\n')
    if (secret[-1:] == "\n"):
        print "Error, new line character at the end of the string. This will not match!"
    elif (len(secret) >= 32):
        print "Error, string too long. Must be less than 32 characters."
    else:
    # create a cipher object using the secret
        cipher = AES.new(secret + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(secret) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING)

    # decode the encoded string
        decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encrypted)

        if (decoded.startswith('FLAG:')):
            print "\n"
            print "Success: "+secret+"\n"
            print decoded+"\n"
            break
        else:
            print 'Wrong password'
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, the error isn't happening anymore, but the script isn't looping for every line in the words.txt

Comment: I did try it, but the problem is when the password isn't right it doesn't go on and try the next line, so the code stops when the password is wrong

Comment: It worked out!, thanks, so i had to put the code inside the `for` , I though it doesn't matter, i mean if it was like javascript where brackets were obligatory to write a function

Answer (score 0):

Reading line by line happens simply like this

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        secret = line #Normally there are no \n at the end

        #Use this is in case you still get the \n
        #secret = line.rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the newline character with a null string:

```
line = f.readline().replace('\n','')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('<filepath>', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    secret = line
    # do something with the line
f.close()
```

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Each line in a file will contain the newline escape character: `\n` at the end of the line.
Here's how you can loop over the file:

```
f = open('words.txt')

for line in f:
    secret = line[:-1] # will extract a substring not containing the newline char

    # then do what you want with secret like:
    do_decoding(secret)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It gives me a code error, can you implement it in the original code?

Comment: It's working now, it was me, but it's not looping through the word list and tries every one, when it tries the first line and it's wrong the code stops and stop trying the other lines

Comment: You should maybe create another question with the new code so we can see what's wrong :)